# How to build SpiderMonkey for ios arm64 arch?

Tags: ios, firefox, clang, clang++, spidermonkey

I build as follow:

```
../configure --with-ios-target=iphoneos --with-ios-version=11.0 --with-ios-min-version=8.0 --with-arch=arm64 --disable-shared-js
```

And receive the following errors:

```
checking whether the chosen combination of compiler flags (-march=arm64) works... configure: error: no
------ config.log ------
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
XtMalloc()
; return 0; }
configure:6418: /usr/bin/clang -c -march=arm64  conftest.c 1>&5
error: unknown target CPU 'arm64'
configure: failed program was:
#line 6411 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
return sizeof(__thumb2__);
; return 0; }
configure:6527: checking whether the chosen combination of compiler flags (-march=arm64) works
configure:6536: /usr/bin/clang -c -march=arm64  conftest.c 1>&5
error: unknown target CPU 'arm64'
configure: failed program was:
#line 6529 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"

int main() {
return 0;
; return 0; }
configure: error: no
```

What is the means of `march`? I receive the same error even if I run with `--with-target=i386`.

How should I do?

Comment: Hi @kcats, Were you able to compile Spidermonkey for arm64?

Comment: @DesertRose emmm.. I'm sorry for that, I skipped this job in my life.